# How to transfer specific row data on to another sheet in same workbook?

Tags: excel, transfer

I have this workbook with 12 sheets each for every month of the year. Combobox for month selection and a user form for data entry. User @K.Davis helped me to get this all working.

Now I've added another sheet named Profit & Loss and what now needed is that when user adds data using user form and it goes into the lets say January 2019 sheet from there some fields gets copied/transferred into the Profit & Loss sheet as well.

The code below is for CommandBox1 on user form. Thanks to @K.Davis for that. I'm not sure if anything needs to go in there or not but putting it out just in case somebody who can help needs to see the code too.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
     Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
   Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim dcc As Long
 Dim abc As Worksheet

 Set abc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)

 With abc

    dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    .Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

End With
TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox3.Text = ""
TextBox4.Text = ""
TextBox5.Text = ""

End Sub
```

How do I have specific rows also entered into the Profit & Loss sheet too? Your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to add the profit-loss to the macro, like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim dcc As Long
 Dim abc As Worksheet, pfl As Worksheet

 Set abc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
 Set pfl = Sheets("ProfitLoss")

With abc

   dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

End With

With pfl
dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
.Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
.Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
end with

TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox3.Text = ""
TextBox4.Text = ""
TextBox5.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, much appreciated. I will give this a quick try to see if it works. Get back in a few! Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks to you. It worked like a charm! I tested it with multiple months and everything works as it should. Profit & Loss have all entries. Now I'll just delete the rows from the macros to only let it transfer what's needed in Profit & Loss sheet, but main this is, it works!! Bundle of thanks for you for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: I posted another question regarding the balance showing on the user form. Can you help with it, by any chance? It'll be much appreciated if you can. Cheers.